# Why is JSON_QUERY sending back a null value?

Tags: json, sql-server

This is driving me nuts, and I don't understand what's wrong with my approach.

I generate a JSON object in SQL like this:

```
    select @output = (  
         select distinct lngEmpNo, txtFullName
         from tblSecret
         for json path, root('result'), include_null_values
    )
```

I get a result like this:

```
{"result":[{"lngEmpNo":696969,"txtFullName":"Clinton, Bill"}]}
```

`ISJSON()` confirms that it's valid JSON, and `JSON_QUERY(@OUTPUT, '$.result')` will return the array `[]` portion of the JSON object... cool!

BUT, I'm trying to use `JSON_QUERY` to extract a specific value:

This gets me a `NULL` value. **Why???????**  I've tried it with the `[0]`, without the `[0]`, and of course, `txtFullName[0]`

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@jsonResponse, '$.result[0].txtFullName');
```

I prefixed with `strict`, `SELECT JSON_QUERY(@jsonResponse, 'strict $.result[0].txtFullName');`, and it tells me this:

```
Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 29
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 't' is found at 
position 18.
```

What am I doing wrong?  What is wrong with my structure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will only extract an **object** or an **array**. You are trying to extract a single **value** so, you need to use [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). For example:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonResponse, '$.result[0].txtFullName');
```